# Show Datum - Error message in console

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following div in HTML:

`<div id = "datum">contents here</div>`

In JavaScript I have the following code to display the date:

```
var myDate= new Date();
document.getElementById('datum').innerHTML = myDate;
```

I get the following error in my console:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null script.js:5:5

I have already tried to put the code above the div tag, since JavaScript reads from top to bottom, but it is still the same issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does document.getElementById('datum') actually produce any results in your page? Can you type it in console and post what comes back?

Comment: No relation with java, Java and Javascript are completly differente languages

Comment: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

Comment: "*I … put the code above the div tag*" so the div doesn't exist when the code runs, so `document.getElementById('datum')` returns `null`, hence the error saying it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may not be getting executed after the DOM loads. Try the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var myDate= new Date();
    document.getElementById('datum').innerHTML = myDate;
});
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you ver much !!